# Obtaining value from td in a row where input button was clicked (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having troubles getting a value from a `td` using `jQuery`.

It keeps saying "undefined" or no result comes out however I edited my code.

I do not know what's wrong...

Here's my code:
(originally, data from mySQL DB should be there in the table. but I omitted them in order to make question briefer)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".delete").click(function(){                    
                var currentrow=$(this).closest('tr');
                var item=currentrow.find('.id').text();
                alert("delete item number:".item);
            });
            $(".approve").click(function(){
                alert("approve!");
            });
            $(".edit").click(function(){
                alert("edit!");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

// Table that contains data 

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='id'>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='button' class='delete' value='Delete'/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='button' class='approve' value='Approve'/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='button' class='edit' value='Edit'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` using a class will return an array of elements. You need to grab the first element and then perform the text lookup, like this:

`var item=$(currentrow.find('.id')[0]).text();`

Also, in Javascript you concatenate strings using + (and not using . like in PHP)

`alert("delete item number:" + item);`

Comment: you're great! it works so fine! thank you very much!

Comment: @BiryongLee if this answer solved your question consider marking it as accepted, so future users know this is the solution for the problem.